# How to remove redundant point from language switching?

Tags: windows-10, language

I have 2 languages in my OS
[image]
and I have 3 points when I click on language in tray:
[image]

Sometimes when I switch language(ctrl+shift) I switch between rus(rus) and rus(us) and sometimes between rus(us) and eng.

It is uncomfortable.

I want to switch only between russian and english languages.

How to remove rus(us) from  list?

Answer (score 0):

Select the `Russian` entry in your first screenshot, your should see three buttons underneath, click `Options`. In the `Language options` screen, you have a `Keyboards` section which should have two entries. Click on one and a `Remove` button should appear.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, all the thing is in the Office.
You need to adjust Office Preffered Languages - delete the redundant language from there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, Peter's solution didn't work for me, since rus(us) doesn't appear in `Keyboards`.

I didn't success to delete rus(us) from the list, but payed attention that if you manually (with a mouse) choose once the rus(rus) option, switching with `Ctrl + Shift` will not give you anymore the rus(us) option.